# Why does android billing library 4 Purchase return an array in getSkus instead of the older getSku single

Tags: android, android-billing

One of the changes made to billing library 4 is that there is no longer a getSku() method for the Purchase class, instead there is a new method getSkus() that returns an arraylist. What is the reason for this? Under what conditions would there be more than one entry in it? It seems very strange to me.